# References on principal G bundle and connections

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, connections, principal-bundles

I am trying to understand about principal G bundle given a Lie group $G$. For that, I started with the action of Lie groups on manifold $M$ and convinced myself that if the action is smooth, proper, and free then orbit space is a smooth manifold and the corresponding projection map gives a fiber bundle $(M,\pi, M/G)$. We call this bundle and any other bundle isomorphic to this bundle a principal $G$ bundle. Only to understand just this it took so much time for me as there are many books with different definitions of principal bundles.

I am comfortable with this definition of a principal bundle and would like to know more  enough to start reading connections on principal bundles. So, I would like to ask for your suggestion regarding some reading materials online on principal bundles. I checked it but did not find it satisfactory. Any suggestions regarding references are welcome.

Please do not add husemoller fiber bundles as it uses some other definition of a principal bundle and not Kobayashi also. I am benifited very much with chapter on Lie group actions on manifolds in Lee’s Book Introduction to manifold. I wish he had published some notes on principal bundles as well. Please do let me know any references along these lines.

Edit: I am now able to understand roughly the concepts of connections, holonomy groups from Kobayashi. Any reference which can supplement this book is most welcome. Now I am reading curvature form and structure equation and do not really understand what they are saying.

Comment: "Some other definition": all these definitions are easily seen to be equivalent.

Comment: I liked José Figueroa-O'Farrill's notes on gauge theory. You might find the first two lectures enlightening: https://empg.maths.ed.ac.uk/Activities/GT/

Comment: @abx, I don't see why 'they' are all obviously equivalent, at least not for the one given by op and the one given by local trivialisation and gluing.

Comment: @abx I will understand that they are equivalent as you said it is needed to understand what a connection is,  Can you give some reference where most of these equivalent definitions arey mentioned.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger : I will see that notes. Thank you.

Comment: @WilleLiou thanks for the comment. Can you suggest some place where I can find most of these definitions discussed.

Comment: I don't know if this is helpful or not, but I find it easier to figure out what a connection on a principal bundle is, if I view the principal bundle as a bundle of frames on a vector bundle and the connection on the principal bundle as a connection on the vector bundle acting on a "moving frame". That helps make the definition of a connection in, say, Kobayashi-Nomizu easier to understand.

Comment: @DeaneYang thanks for your comment. Can you give some reference where you have seen about bundl elf frames on a vector bundle.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm terrible with references. I usually learn bits and pieces from different sources and then try to put it all together in a consistent framework (of which choosing a consistent notation that I like is important). The problem is that there are three distinct ways to approach anything: local coordinates, vector fields, and differential forms ("moving frames").

Comment: I find the moving frame approach using differential forms the easiest, because the Maurer-Cartan equations are easiest to use in that form. Also, it's easier to view $G$ as a subgroup of $GL(n)$ (the fancy way to say that is the fiber of the vector bundle is a faithful representation of $G$ but you don't need to know that at first).

Comment: The wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_form#Principal_bundles looks like a reasonable explanation of all this.

Comment: Have you tried reading Chapter 8 of Volume II of Spivak's tomes on differential geometry (where (*) mentioned early on refers to an equation at the bottom of page 280 in Chapter 7)?  It is somewhat formula-intensive, but does carefully address the passage between principal Ehresmann connections on principal bundles and the more classical Koszul connection viewpoint on rank-$n$ vector bundles, and has a nice Summary at the end of the chapter for passing among various viewpoints on connections.  The end of the Wikipedia article on connections that @DeaneYang mentions ties up related loose ends.

Comment: I have not read that. I will read that and will come back if I have any further questions @nfdc23

Comment: By the way, the published edition of Spivak's Volume II to which I referred (for the page number of (*), for example) is the LaTeX version, not the original published version (which probably had different page numbers).

Comment: @nfdc23 I was not particular about page number... I will have a Lok at those two chapters.   Thanks

Answer (score 4):

"Foundations of Differential Geometry" by Kobayashi and Nomizu has a good introduction to principal bundles and connections on them.  In fact, this is presented at the beginning and is used as the basis for their presentation of classical (in the present) differential geometry.

Comment: I have mentioned not to mention kobayashi book as I am already reading that and not very comfortable with that way. So, asked for another reference.

Answer (score 3):

Try the book by Michor, Kolar & Slovak titled *Natural Operations in Differential Geometry*, it's rather dense so if you're uncomfortable with Kobayashi & Nomizu you might find it doesn't work for you. It has a couple of chapters on vector, fibre, principal and jet bundles. It's also available as a free download. It's very comprehensive and best treated as a reference text.

Another book to try is Saunders *The Geometry of Jet Bundles*, this is more accessible but the notation is very heavy; he goes up to the variational bicomplex.

Also Moritas *The Geometry of Differential Forms*, I haven't read this apart from a brief look at its contents, but it looks very interesting.

Answer (score 2):

I realised one **can not (should not)** escape from reading Kobayashi and Nomizu’s book.

Other books that helped me to learn more about principal bundles are

1. [Differential Geometry: Connections, Curvature, and Characteristic Classes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3319550829) by Loring W. Tu
2. Connections, Curvature, and Cohomology Volumes 1,2,3 by Werner Hildbert Greub, Stephen Halperin, James S. Vanstone, Ray Vanstone

Comment: I answered this because some one upvoted this question before couple of hours.. I thought it is good to to tell what helped me.

Comment: Personally I like the three volume books "Connections, Curvature, and Cohomology" very much. However, these books are out of print. By the way, it seems the terms used in, say Volume I, of these books are not quite standard.

Answer (score 2):

I like Chern's short and easy *Vector bundles with a connection*, in Chern, **Global Differential Geometry**, M.A.A., 1989. Chern focuses on vector bundles but does so by using simple examples of principal bundles. Chern gives some serious theorems that motivate learning the subject.

Comment: I tried multiple number of times to read that article. Could not finish. I liked it though +1